# What is the channelID byfn-sys-channel in the basic network (Fabric Samples)?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

While generating orderer genesis block the channel ID supplied to configtxgen is **byfn-sys-channel** despite the name of the channel being  **mychannel**

Can somebody throw up some light about it's significance. Also this change has been incorporated in 1.4 release, it wasn't there in the earlier releases.

Answer (score 1):

The channelID given while generating the genesis block is referring to the system channel which should contain consortium details, Eg. Org which should be part of the consortium is defined in this channel's MSP.

By default in earlier versions it uses `testchainid` as the system channel and allowed overriding options using `-channelID` option. In recent versions it was suggested to make this a necessary field.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would just like to add a point that in the recent versions too it is not a necessary flag , as while generating the genesis block in first network of the fabric samples the channelID is not supplied.

Comment: Ohh, Thanks for that, I've been using v1.2. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I tried running the basic network, the one which did not supplied the channelID flag. You were right, now Omitting the channel ID is deprecated and hence a warning is shown and in future versions it would be a necessity to pass the flag.